# Консоль в C# - Обработчик команд!

Tags: c#, windows, .net, консоль

Доброе время суток, господа!

Помогите нубу)

Код C#:

```
List<string> cmds = new List<string>();
{
    Console.Write("Hello>");

       string line = Console.ReadLine();
       switch (line)
       {
            case "print":
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Some print!");
               }
               break;
               case "do":
               {
                   SomeDo();
               }
               break;
               case "clear":
               {
                   Console.Clear();
               }
               break;
        }
}
```

Вопрос:
Как поймать exception, скажем, если пользователь вводит что-то не из перечня? И как в этом случае или в случае успешного выполнения команды вернуться к **Console.Write("Hello>");** и продолжить работу?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обычно делают как-то так:

```
Dictionary<string, Action> commands = new Dictionary<string, Action>()
{
    { "print", (Action)(() => Console.WriteLine("Some print!")) },
    { "do", SomeDo },
    { "clear", (Action)(() => Console.Clear) }
};

while (true)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (commands.ContainsKey(input))
        commands[input]();
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized command: " + input);
}
```

Возможно, вам надо будет ещё предусмотреть наличие аргументов у команд.

---

Для аргументов можно сделать что-то наподобие такого: заменяем `Action` на `Action<IEnumerable<string>>`.

```
Dictionary<string, Action<IEnumerable<string>>> commands =
    new Dictionary<string, Action<IEnumerable<string>>>()
{
    { "print", MakeSimpleCommand(() => Console.WriteLine("Some print!")) },
    { "do", SomeDo },
    { "clear", MakeSimpleCommand(() => Console.Clear) }
};

while (true)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    var tokens = SplitIntoTokens(input);
    var command = tokens.FirstOrDefault();
    if (command == null)
        continue;
    if (commands.ContainsKey(command))
    {
        try
        {
            commands[command](tokens.Skip(1));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Execution failed: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unrecognized command: " + command);
    }
}

Action<IEnumerable<string>> MakeSimpleCommand(Action a)
{
    return args =>
    {
        if (args.Any())
            throw new ArgumentException("this command doesn't support args");
        a();
    }
}

IEnumerable<string> SplitIntoTokens(string s)
{
    // тут надо бы что-то похитрее, как минимум учитывать группировку
    // кавычками и escape-символы
    return s.Split(null as char[], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
}
```

---

Если вы хотите реализовать историю и редактирование строки более удобно, посмотрите в сторону [реализации readline на C#](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/mono/mcs/tools/csharp/getline.cs) от одного из главных разработчиков Mono (её можно просто подключить в проект, [вот](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Aug-26.html) пример использования).